# Month function on googlesheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using function `=MONTH(A2)` & `=TEXT(A2,"MMM")` to get the month number. However, If the date is blank it by default says 12 & Dec.

Any suggestion for a function which will say blank " " instead of default 12 or Dec?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
=if(A2="", "", MONTH(A2))

=if(A2="", "", TEXT(A2,"MMM"))
```